# В контейнерах docker не определяется доменное имя dns

Tags: docker, dns, centos8

Имеется `CentOS 8`

```
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 8.1.1911 (Core)
Release:        8.1.1911
Codename:       Core
```

Имеется `docker`

```
Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea
```

ifconfig centos:

```
br-1d476f57364d: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.20.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.20.255.255
        ether 02:42:5a:ce:83:b7  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 19  bytes 1036 (1.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:45ff:fea5:7546  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:45:a5:75:46  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 111  bytes 5714 (5.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 148  bytes 12637 (12.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet XX.XX.XX.XX  netmask 255.255.255.128  broadcast XX.XX.XX.XX
        inet6 XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 XXXX::XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 320281  bytes 31142714 (29.7 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4632  bytes 685411 (669.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 184  bytes 15084 (14.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 184  bytes 15084 (14.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.11.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  destination 10.11.0.1
        inet6 fe80::4214:8b71:cc09:5547  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 19  bytes 1036 (1.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

/etc/resolv.conf:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search kz
nameserver 195.210.46.132
nameserver 195.210.46.195
```

Пинг:

```
# ping google.com
PING google.com(lg-in-x8b.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4010:c08::8b)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from lg-in-x8b.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4010:c08::8b): icmp_seq=1 ttl=45 time=73.6 ms
64 bytes from lg-in-x8b.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4010:c08::8b): icmp_seq=2 ttl=45 time=71.8 ms
```

docker networks:

```
docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
62a202796de7        bridge              bridge              local
71cfb87084cd        host                host                local
93b5ee7c439f        none                null                local
1d476f57364d        root_default        bridge              local
```

Запускаю контейнер:

```
docker run -it --rm debian /bin/bash
```

Выполняю ping:

```
root@5132d5db88cf:/#  ping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution


root@5132d5db88cf:/# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=43 time=71.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=43 time=70.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=43 time=70.8 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 6ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 70.820/70.975/71.286/0.377 ms
root@5132d5db88cf:/# ping 8.8.4.4
PING 8.8.4.4 (8.8.4.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.4.4: icmp_seq=1 ttl=43 time=72.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.4.4: icmp_seq=2 ttl=43 time=72.2 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.4.4: icmp_seq=3 ttl=43 time=72.2 ms
^C
--- 8.8.4.4 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 5ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 72.213/72.424/72.844/0.429 ms
```

По имени не пингует

Файл  /etc/resolv.conf в контейнере:

```
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

ip addr в контейнере:

```
root@5132d5db88cf:/# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
13: eth0@if14: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 172.17.0.2/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Почему не резолвятся имена?

Если я укажу `--network=host` при создании контейнера то все работает.

```
docker run -it --network=host  --rm debian /bin/bash

root@m:/# ping google.com
PING google.com(lf-in-x64.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4010:c07::64)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from lf-in-x64.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4010:c07::64): icmp_seq=1 ttl=45 time=68.7 ms
64 bytes from lf-in-x64.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4010:c07::64): icmp_seq=2 ttl=45 time=68.6 ms
64 bytes from lf-in-x64.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4010:c07::64): icmp_seq=3 ttl=45 time=69.5 ms
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: вероятно, в вашей сети режется некоторый трафик. попробуйте привести `/etc/resolv.conf` в контейнере к тому же виду, что и у хост-машины.

Comment: Вот @aleksandrbarakin предполагает что режется трафик, в данном случае мы говорим про ограничение udp по 53 порту. 
Зайдите в контейнер, поставьте туда dig и попробуйте с помощью него зарезолвить некоторые адреса обращаясь к разным dns, тогда картина прояснится.